# Error: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to insert data into MySQL using Python.

What is the cause of this error?

> ProgrammingError: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing
>   prepared statement

My python codes:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                         database='popsww2017',
                         user='root',
                         password='')
records_to_insert = [('---2q7vcZGU', 'Partner-provided', '35', '9s1Pvm0U8Gg8mRavZhVXdg', 'A663893851990558', '1066/2016/HDHT-Pops-Kha Ly', '1467', '0.100598')]
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO raw_music (`Video_ID`, `Content_Type`, `Video_Duration`, `Channel_ID`, `Asset_ID`, `Asset_Labels`, `Owned_Views`, `Partner_Revenue`) VALUES ( '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s') "
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
result  = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query,records_to_insert)
connection.commit()
```

My tables:

```
Video_ID    varchar(50) utf8_unicode_ci     
Content_Type    varchar(100)    utf16_unicode_ci        
Video_Duration  int(11)         
Channel_ID  varchar(100)    utf8_unicode_ci     
Asset_ID    varchar(50) utf32_unicode_ci        
Asset_Labels    varchar(400)    utf32_unicode_ci        
Owned_Views int(20)         
Partner_Revenue float
```

Comment: When an answer points out bugs in your question, it's customary **not to fix the bugs in your question.** Otherwise the page is difficult to follow for later viewers (e.g. me ;-).  I see the three bugs (1) records_to_insert needed to be a list, and (2) it needed to be passed to executemany(), (3) remove the quotes around the %s symbols. Was that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the [executemany method parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html):

```
result  = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query,records_to_insert)
```

> MySQLCursor.executemany() Method
>   Syntax:
>
> ```
> cursor.executemany(operation, seq_of_params)
> ```
>
> This method prepares a database operation (query or command) and executes it against all parameter sequences or mappings found in the sequence seq_of_params.

Also your syntax is wrong (remove quotes), use the following instead:

```
records_to_insert = [('---2q7vcZGU', 'Partner-provided', '35', '9s1Pvm0U8Gg8mRavZhVXdg', 'A663893851990558', '1066/2016/HDHT-Pops-Kha Ly', '1467', '0.100598')]
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO raw_music (`Video_ID`, `Content_Type`, `Video_Duration`, `Channel_ID`, `Asset_ID`, `Asset_Labels`, `Owned_Views`, `Partner_Revenue`) VALUES ( %s, %s , %s , %s, %s , %s , %s , %s) "
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
result  = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
```

Comment: Still did not get you. What i have been missing?

Comment: @AnalyticsPOPSWW you sent `sql_insert_query` twice to `executemany` instead of using `records_to_insert` as the second parameter

Comment: Oh sorry. My mistake. But even I change that line. I still got the same error

Comment: I changed like yours but still got the error **ProgrammingError: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement**

Comment: It finally works :). These stupid lines `'%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s'` made me exhausted.

Answer (score 3):

the secret to make it work it's to add a comma at the end of the single valued tuple.

Example:

```
# a tuple
to_insert = ('A value to insert'**,**)
```

In this case:

```
records_to_insert = [('---2q7vcZGU', 'Partner-provided', 35, '9s1Pvm0U8Gg8mRavZhVXdg', 'A663893851990558', '1066/2016/HDHT-Pops-Kha Ly', 1467, 0.100598)**,**]
```

It works for single valued tuples.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`executemany` function is used when you need to insert many rows in the database. And the second parameter should be a list containing values to be inserted in these different rows. So either you modify the code to the following: 
(Note that I have added square brackets `[]` to `records_to_insert`, making it a list)

```
records_to_insert = [('---2q7vcZGU', 'Partner-provided', 35, '9s1Pvm0U8Gg8mRavZhVXdg', 'A663893851990558', '1066/2016/HDHT-Pops-Kha Ly', 1467, 0.100598)]
sql_insert_query = "INSERT INTO raw_music (`Video_ID`, `Content_Type`, `Video_Duration`, `Channel_ID`, `Asset_ID`, `Asset_Labels`, `Owned_Views`, `Partner_Revenue`) VALUES ( '%s', '%s' , %d , '%s', '%s' , '%s' , %d , %f) "
cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
result  = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: I tried like you mentioned but still got the same error

Comment: is it just one row to insert?

Comment: If I have one row. I can use `execute` instead of `executemany`. I know that. But that is not help at all

Comment: No. The problem is this `'%s', '%s' , %d , '%s', '%s' , '%s' , %d , %f)`

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!