# Incorrect number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm having a heck of a time getting the mysql.connector module to work. I'd really like to find some accurate documentation on it. By hit and by miss, I have arrived here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_civicrm_address.py", line 80, in <module>
    cursor.execute(mysql_select_query, address_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 1210, in execute
    msg="Incorrect number of arguments " \
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement
```

Here is the program (it's a bit messy because I have tried so many things to get it to work). Aside from the fact that the update is not working at all, what is causing the error? There is only one parameter and it is accounted for.

```
import sys
import mysql.connector
import csv
import os
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode


#Specify the import file
try:


    inputCSV = 'geocoded_rhode_island_export.csv'

#Open the file and give it a handle

    csvFile = open(inputCSV, 'r')

#Create a reader object for the input file

    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter = ',')

except IOError as e:
    print("The input file ", inputCSV, " was not found", e)
    exit()


try:
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='wordpress',
                             user='wp_user',
                             password='secret!',
                             use_pure=True)
   cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print( "Failed to connect to database: {}".format(error))
    exit()

try:

    record_count = 0

    for row in reader:
        contact_id,address_id,last_name, first_name, middle_name, longitude, latitude = row
        print(row)

   #Update single record now

        print(address_id)
        cursor.execute(

        """
            update civicrm_address
            set 
            geo_code_1 = %s,
            geo_code_2 = %s
        where
            id = %s 
        and
            location_type_id = %s 
        """,
        (longitude, latitude, address_id, 6)
        )
        conn.commit
        print(cursor.rowcount)
        print("Record updated successfully")
        mysql_select_query = """
        select
            id,
            geo_code_1,
            geo_code_2
        from
            civicrm_address
        where
            id = %s
        """
        input = (address_id)


        cursor.execute(mysql_select_query, address_id)
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print(record)
        record_count = record_count + 1




finally:
    print(record_count, " records updated")
    #closing database connection.
    if(conn.is_connected()):
        conn.close()
        print("connection is closed")
```

Comment: try to change `cursor.execute` to `cursor.executemany`

Comment: I am only trying to fetch one row with the id equal to the address_id

Comment: Did you check this [Error: 1210: Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53185081/6194097) question?

Comment: I did change it to cursor.executetmany and that got rid of the "incorrect number of arguments' error.

I am expecting that after executing the select statement with the address_id, fetchone will retrieve the row with that id and print(record) will print the columns used in the select statement. All it is printing is none.

The update statement is not working either. None of the records in the database are updated with the geocodes.

Comment: keep it with `cursor.executemany` and then add @Mureinik suggested

Comment: When I add the comma is he suggested (address_id,) I get the incorrect number of arguments error. Without the comma, I get no errors reported but the query is not retrieving any records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196422/discussion-between-kushan-gunasekera-and-vietyank).

Answer (score 0):

The is an error in the code

```
conn.commit
```

should be

```
conn.commit()
```